# using XalanDOMString in a std::map or convert to string

Tags: c++, dictionary, xalan

I need to fetch few rows  from DB , store the pair in a std::map.
later Use getNamespaceForPrefix method of xalan API to check the pair with matching prefix.

```
const XalanDOMString* PrefixUrlResolver::getNamespaceForPrefix(const XalanDOMString &prefix ) const{
url = XalanDOMString(tMap[prefix.c_str()]);
return &url;
}
```

PrefixUrlResolver is derived from PrefixResolver class of xalan API.

The values in map is populated from the table as:-

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> TStrStrMap;
typedef std::pair<std::string, std::string> TStrStrPair;
tMap.insert(TXlnDOMStrPair(tableStructure.prefix_value, tableStructure.url_value));
```

The problem is I am unable to convert the XalanDOMString &prefix to string for using in a map and later reconvert the string retrieved from map to XalanDOMString.

I tried using map of  but it didnt worked too.

Comment: It may be a subtle reason I'm not seeing, but why not just code a custom comparator for your map that uses `XalanDOMString::compare(XalanDOMString const&)`, then simply use `XalanDOMString` as your map key type in the first place. IOW, cut out the conversions and just use what you have naturally as key material.

Comment: I am totally new to c++ and Xalan stuff.
If I simply do this Will IT work?
    const XalanDOMString* PrefixUrlResolver::getNamespaceForPrefix(const XalanDOMString &prefix ) const{
    TStrStrMap::iterator p;
           for(p = tMap.begin(); p!=tMap.end(); ++p)
           {
               if(prefix.compare(p->first))
               {
                 return p->second;
               }
            }

    return &url;
    }